# Как загружать только текстовое содержание?

Tags: php

Есть скрипт на PHP, он заходит на определенную страницу, находит там определенное текстовое значение и сохраняет в БД. Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы он не загружал разные javascript'ы, html теги и прочее, а только текстовое содержание?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сразу выделить только тот текст что нужен не возможно. Сначала нужно загрузить всю страницу, обработать её и результат обработки сохранить в базу данных. Для выделения нужного текста из всей страницы нужно сделать регулярку. Но здесь есть своя неприятность, как только на сайте сменится оформление или верстка, регулярку придется переписывать.

Answer (score 0):

[Функция strip_tags](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php):

> Удаляет HTML и PHP тэги из строки.

Comment: Изначально выгружается вся страница, а потом только начинает работать стрип-тэгс, поэтому не подходит. Мне нужно, чтобы сразу загружалось только текстовое содержание. Что-то типа запрета на загрузку html-тегов и скриптов.

Comment: @nick777 а как вы себе представляете возможность заставить ччужой сервер выдавать данные, которые нужны вам? В потоке байтов хтмл-тег от текста ничем не отличается.

Comment: Дополню ответ: очень юзабельно вот такое:

<pre>$str = strip_tags(str_replace('<', ' <', $str));</pre>

ибо strip_tags не выставляет пробелы между соседними тегами и, например, результат от <pre><span>Цена<span class="us">у нас</span><span><b>250</b>руб</pre> = <pre>Ценау нас250руб</pre>